# How to know if the insert function to mysql is done successfully?

Tags: php, mysql

Inside my php I have a function which creates a connection to my db, insert info and closes the connection. I want to use the same function to write into another db as well. But before I attempt to make connection the other db I need to know that the first query is executed successfully. Is there a way to make the php wait until the insert function is done? like a while loop or something?

Comment: Why, exactly, are you writing to separate databases?

Comment: cause the purpose of each is different and makes is easier to analyze later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you use `INSERT DELAYED` the insert is synchronous. Test the return value in order to see if the insert succeeded.

Comment: +1 However just because "INSERT" succeeded, doesn't imply the transaction was committed (even if it often is with autocommit). Just something to keep in mind; the close could perform a rollback.

Comment: @pst there doesn't seem to be any mention of transactions here though, especially since the operation seems to span two databases.

Comment: @Crashspeeder "Just something to keep in mind" :-) Although perhaps spanning two databases is a better reason to use explicit transactions ... depends.

Comment: So how would I know the right time to call the function again with new arguments to add data to another db? lets say the server is not that quick and it takes time to add data to the databaseA and I also want to add data to databaseB using the same function.

Comment: @Kourosh As Ignacio said, it's synchronous.  The script won't move on until the operation is over.

Comment: ok, now I got it. sorry I'm not native to english. So I'll just call the function twice and everything should be ok.